# How to make Mongodb 27017 port available on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

After installing and starting `mongodb` on Google **Ubuntu** instance I can verify that 'mongodb' is running with: `sudo systemctl status mongodb`:

```
● mongodb.service - LSB: An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongodb; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-02-27 19:41:17 UTC; 57min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 13 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 71.7M
      CPU: 14.520s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─1914 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
Feb 27 19:41:15 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: An object/document-oriented database...
Feb 27 19:41:16 instance-1 mongodb[1827]:  * Starting database mongodb
Feb 27 19:41:17 instance-1 mongodb[1827]:    ...done.
Feb 27 19:41:17 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: An object/document-oriented database.
```

It all looks good. But by some reason another application running on the same machine is not able to connect to the what-seems-to-be-running-properly `mongodb`.

Running `nmap 127.0.0.1` returns:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
631/tcp open  ipp
```

There is no `mongodb's port # 27017 listed there as *open*.
Interesting that the firewall is disabled. How can I assure the`mongodb`port`27017` is open and available to other applications?

Comment: Provide `netstat -nlp` and `ps aux | grep mongo` output, pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nmap` scan all common port, mongodb use port `27017` by default which is not listed in default `nmap` default port scan. On the other hand, you can specify the port manually :

```
nmap -p 27017  127.0.0.1
```

You will get :

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
27017/tcp open  unknown
```

If you see `STATE` close, this means mongodb is not running and then you should begin to worry about it

Or as suggested by @Dimitri using `netstat` such as :

```
netstat -tulpn
```

which gives :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```